# Unable to Show Progress Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

I'm using `ProgressDialog` to show a `loading` page in my `android app` .

My code looks like :

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setMessage("please Wait ...");
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.progress_dialog_style);
            dialog.show();
            String toastMsg = null;
            LoginService loginService = new LoginService(LoginActivity.this);
            ProfileDetails profileDetails = loginService.checkLogin(mobile_number.getText().toString().trim(), password.getText().toString().trim());
            if(profileDetails != null && loginService.changeLogin(MainActivity.LOGIN_YES, mobile_number.getText().toString().trim())) {
                toastMsg = MainActivity.LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL;
            }
  if(profileDetails == null) {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
           }
        });
   }
```

and then i perform some `DB Operations` and get some data

and i use `dialog.dismiss()`.

If i get data successfully i use `startActivity(intent);`

Here

`i)` if i use `dialog.dismiss()` when i run the code i am not able to see the Dialog.

`ii)` When i remove the `dialog.dimiss()` section i am able to see the Dialog but unable to close it.

Please resolve this problem.

Thank You

Log i got is

```
12-16 00:12:42.325    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-16 00:12:42.325    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa34423e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-16 00:12:42.632    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-16 00:12:42.632    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa34422e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-16 00:12:42.804    2146-2160/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 58.235ms for cause Background
12-16 00:12:42.937    2146-2156/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 38.186ms
12-16 00:12:42.938    2146-2160/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 19.448ms
12-16 00:12:42.946    2146-2160/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8670(494KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 5MB/5MB, paused 21.810ms total 130.763ms
12-16 00:12:43.105    2146-2160/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 61.760ms
12-16 00:12:43.171    2146-2146/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating  I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-16 00:12:43.245    2146-2160/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1796(126KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(76KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 5MB/9MB, paused 12.887ms total 76.159ms
12-16 00:12:43.803    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-16 00:12:43.803    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3fdece0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-16 00:12:44.892    1294-1313/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed mycompany.com.weekendmovierating/mycompany.weekendmovierating.activity.SelectLanguageActivity: +2s541ms
12-16 00:12:45.023    2146-2146/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 12-16 00:12:45.055    1545-6738/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d6dc0
 12-16 00:12:45.082    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7da1d0
 12-16 00:12:45.093    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d8870
12-16 00:12:45.148    2146-2172/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab7d85d0
12-16 00:12:45.342    2146-2146/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity mycompany.weekendmovierating.activity.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ffa0769 V.E...... R......D 0,0-760,192} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
        at mycompany.weekendmovierating.activity.LoginActivity.login(LoginActivity.java:87)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-16 00:12:45.371    2146-2156/mycompany.com.weekendmovierating W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 25.085ms
 12-16 00:12:45.397    1294-1305/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failed looking up window
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@aa60cd1 does not exist
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8723)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8714)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2697)
        at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:187)
        at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:242)
        at com.android.server.wm.Session.onTransact(Session.java:130)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    progress.dismiss();
  }
```

Dismiss your dialog like this in runnable thread.

Comment: I tested my code with the answer you said. After adding the lines in your answer
i am unable to see the `Progress Dialog`.

Comment: Please post your complete code here

Comment: I have edited the previous code in my question . Please check it

Comment: Just try it simple like this first...              ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
dialog.setMessage("please Wait ...");
            dialog.show();             and then just simple dismiss it wherever you want dialog.dismiss();

Comment: Revert back me with error

Comment: If i use `dimiss()` inside Runnable or in any `if` or `else block` there is no `dialog` appearning. I have used `dialog.hide()` but no use.

Comment: Even if i use `dialog.hide()` the `dialog` is not displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98015/discussion-between-nimmagadda-gowtham-and-abhishek).

Comment: Try it simply once as I mentioned in comment

Comment: Hi. I have modified the code as u said in your previous comment
And i used dismiss() only if there is no data from Database that is in failure case
And now there is a dialog when the data is correct
And there is not any dialog when there is no data from database